Can slicers combine vase mode and non-vase mode in the same print?
I would like to combine a non-vase ('conventional'?) base with a vase mode upper portion of a print.
Reference project is a vase-mode Gridfinity 1x1 container; aiming for a 1x2 single compartment and a 1x3 single or dual compartment, 6U.
While the original is entirely vase mode, that will not work for this due to the separate bases with hollows for the grid.  Printing tilted seems impractical.
Can slicers e.g. switch modes at a certain layer?
Is there an existing program to combine (stack) G-code from separately sliced models?

Gblend can stack g-code files. Your use case is mentioned in the readme:


You can mix different objects. For example, you might blend a base and an object.


